# Displaying a UITableView from a nib file is not the same as creating it programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I'm facing an issue using a `UITableViewController` from a nib file. As a workaround I'm creating it programmatically and it's fine but still the behavior struggles me... Let me explain the issue.

### Nib file

I have a `Table.xib` file that contains only a `UITableView` which is attached to the file owner's `view` member (as well as the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets). The file owner is of type `MyTableViewController` (which extends `UITableViewController`). The `UITableView` is defined as grouped style and everything else is default settings

### UITableViewController

Nothing fancy here, I set that the view must contain one section and one cell in the section. A default cell is returned. (source here: http://pastebin.com/FuEK71Cr)

### AppDelegate

I want to display the table directly after launching and my issue raises when I load the controller using:

```
UITableViewController *startCtrl = [[MyTableController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Table" bundle:nil];
```

Doing so will display the table but the top of it is above the top of the screen. In other words I have to scroll upwards to see the top of the table, sounds like a wtf to me :)

Instead if I init the controller programmatically and set the `UITableView` in grouped style it's working fine:

```
UITableViewController *startCtrl = [[MyTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So is it the frame of the tableview that is causing problems or is it the table view performing unexplained scrolling? I've had trouble with `UITableViewController` in the past. I never use it now, instead I use a plain `UIViewController` and add the `UITableViewDataSource/Delegate` methods manually.  Other people dislike `UITableViewController` too http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/09/24/dont-use-uitableviewcontroller-really/ and http://flux88.com/blog/is-uitableviewcontroller-useless/

Comment: The issue is not the scrolling, it's the positioning of the table. Thanks for the links, I don't feel alone anymore :)